# Add SMTP Email Address and set as default, right after mailbox enabling as 365

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have the following, working well, After connecting to Exchange 2016 ( On-premise ):

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "`n Please provide AD-USERNAME to Migrate";

Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $username -RemoteRoutingAddress($username+'@MYORG.mail.onmicrosoft.com')

sleep 30

Get-RemoteMailbox $username|Set-RemoteMailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$true
```

What i need to do now, is to set the a NEW smtp address per each mailbox that is created using that syntax.

In a diffrent script, i used something like the following to add additional SMTP`s and set them as
default for mailboxes:

```
    Set-RemoteMailbox $username -EmailAddresses @{add="$smtp"}
    Set-RemoteMailbox $username -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $false -PrimarySmtpAddress "$smtp"
```

Not sure, thats going to work here the same way, amyeb something more of that sort?

```
Get-RemoteMailbox $username| Set-RemoteMailbox $username -EmailAddresses @{add=$username+'@MYORG.com'}
```

Well im not sure where to go from here with the syntax to do what i need...would love some help.

Thanks in advance, everyone !

Answer (score 0):

As you are in a hybrid On-Prem and Cloud Exchange environment, and you wish to add a new email address alias to an existing on-prem mailbox, the below is how its done.

**Set-RemoteMailbox cmdlet** - configures Exchange attributes for an **on-premises mail user**. The configuration set on the on-premises mail user is synchronized to its associated mailbox in the service.

**Get-RemoteMailbox cmdlet** retrieves the **mail-related attributes** of a **mail user** in the **on-premises Active Directory**. It **doesn't retrieve** the attributes of the **associated cloud-based mailbox**. Most of the mail-related attributes of the on-premises mail user and the associated cloud-based mailbox should be the same. However, the cloud-based mailbox has additional attributes that you can't view by using this cmdlet.

**Example Script to Add a New SMTP Address To Existing Mailbox**

```
$users = ("user1", "user2")
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $smtpdomain = "@MYORG.mail.onmicrosoft.com" # domain name
    $username = $user.ToString() # user name to string 
    $emailadd = $username + $smtpdomain # String the user's prefix and new suffix together
    $emailadd = $emailadd.ToString() # email address to string
    Get-RemoteMailbox $user | Set-RemoteMailbox -EmailAddresses @{add=$newSMTP} # add email address
}
```

**Use Exchange Online PowerShell to add email addresses to multiple mailboxes**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-user-mailboxes/add-or-remove-email-addresses

**csv file containing usernames & email addresses**

column headers are Mailbox and NewEmailAddress
the delimiter is ','

```
Mailbox,NewEmailAddress
Dan Jump,danj@northamerica.contoso.com
David Pelton,davidp@northamerica.contoso.com
Kim Akers,kima@northamerica.contoso.com
Janet Schorr,janets@northamerica.contoso.com
Jeffrey Zeng,jeffreyz@northamerica.contoso.com
Spencer Low,spencerl@northamerica.contoso.com
Toni Poe,tonip@northamerica.contoso.com
```

**Run the following command to use the data in the CSV file to add the email address to each mailbox specified in the CSV file.**

```
Import-CSV "C:\temp\AddEmailAddress.csv" | ForEach {Set-RemoteMailbox $_.Mailbox -EmailAddresses @{add=$_.NewEmailAddress}
```

[image: adding two strings together]

Answer (score 0):

We've solved the issue internally by adding `-PrimarySmtpAddress` To the initial `Enable-RemoteMailbox` string, and by removing `EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$true`
Alltogether.

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "`n Please provide AD-USERNAME to Migrate";

Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $username -RemoteRoutingAddress($username+'@MYORG.mail.onmicrosoft.com') -PrimarySmtpAddress($username+'@MYORG.com')

sleep 30

## Removed ## >> Get-RemoteMailbox $username|Set-RemoteMailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$true
```

I appreciate everyone's effort. Thanks.